# Using Uploadify within an Accordion and external Upload Button

Tags: jquery, flash, accordion, uploadify

I have a jQuery UI Accordion with 3 elements and an uploadify upload button on the first element.
The Auto option of Uploadify is set to false so uploadify only uploads when startupload is called.

Now the button to start the upload is on the second element of the accordion.

When I press it I get the error "Call to StartUpload failed" in the developer console.

I think this is caused by the accordion hiding the first element with the flash upload button inside and flash stopps working when hidden.

So is there any way to make this scenario working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`startUpload` is not a method of uploadify, it is a method of `SWFUpload` and therefore you cannot directly call it from "uploadified" input component.

(I presume that your spelling in your actual code is correct. It is neither startupload, nor StartUpload.)

Somewhere at line 531 (jquery.uploadify.js v3.2) you can read this:

```
   var $this        = $(this),
       swfuploadify = $this.data('uploadify');

   ...

   swfuploadify.startUpload();
```

Instead, if you want to activate the upload for the files being queued, you can call

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');
```

For details: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/upload/

It is not the jQuery UI accordion control that causes you this problem. In our projects we have used this control within dialogs, accordions, without any problem.

By the way, I recommend you to look at this patch too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11918925/1268910