# Uploadify not clickable in JQuery UI's Dialog and Firefox 17

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, dialog, click, uploadify

This is a really weird issue. I've first read the answer from Maayan Glikser on this question which looked similar : [Uploadify inside Jquery UI Dialog => Chrome & Opera bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915918/uploadify-inside-jquery-ui-dialog-chrome-opera-bugs)

It didn't work at all. Let me explain my problem.

I have 3 different Uplodify (Flash version) controls on my website (not on the same pages), only one of them doesn't work and it's the one that is inside a JQuery UI Dialog. Basically, the button is visible but not clickable. The problem occurs only for this particular control, the others behave normally.

So I tried adjusting the z-index inside the javascript, it didn't change anything. Then I tried adding *manually* (through firebug's "edit html" feature) a `<br />` at the beginning of the container generated by uploadify and bam, the button became clickable

I then tried adding the `<br />` on page load with `$("#fmuploader").prepend('<br />')` and nothing happened, the line break was added but the button wasn't clickable. When I added *manually* a blank space it became clickable again.

I believe there is some kind of paint event that gets triggered when you manually edit the page from firebug which makes the button suddenly become clickable, but I'm really wondering if I can make it finally work as intended without asking all my firefox-using visitors to install firebug :)

It is really hard to explain so I have setup a small test page at this address : *deleted* (**edit**: the test page is now offline on the production environment and is no longer reachable)

This reproduces exactly the problem I have.

Load the page, click the link to open the popup, open firebug, find the uploader's container  `<div id="fmuploader" class="uploadify" style="height: 30px; width: 120px;">` and just add a blank space after the opening tag. The button becomes clickable.

The problem occurs on Firefox 17 with no add-ons except firebug and Flash 11. The problem does not occur on IE 7/8/9 and Chrome on the same machine.

***Update***: I tested it with Firefox 15 and wasn't able to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but found that updating Firebug to version 1.11 sorted it.

It was only seemed to be the issue in verstion 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a change in the Firefox 17 security model means that minified version of jQuery breaks when using Firebug.  Plenty of jQuery based stuff has stopped working for me in Firefox 17 unless I disable Firebug.

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/08/20/exposing-objects-to-content-safely/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPConnect_wrappers

Comment: I'll just blame Firefox 17 for that one, and cross my fingers hoping it gets fixed.